# How to set alarm time based on current time?

Tags: android-alarms

I want to set an alarm after 5 min of current time in my application.I am using calendar.getMinutes()+5 to get the current time (minutes).But its not working.can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// add 5 minutes to the calendar object
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
```